# How do I remove a component from all pages after adding it to all

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I added an Image to the header of all pages.  Is there a way to remove this image from all pages in one go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option "Display on all pages" in Module Settings. Maybe that helps.

Comment: After so many pages have been added and copied, etc...How do you find the original module so you can uncheck the option?